# Behavior of If constexpr in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

Even having a lot a questions about this topic, I am having more and more problems. I think the problem is in understanding the meaning of certain words. All quotes below are from [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If)

1. What does 'discarded' mean in the text below? I understand 'discarded' as something never compiled/touched, something that, whatever it is (like random characters that would be errors), it won't interfere in the rest of the program.

> In a constexpr if statement, the value of condition must be a
> contextually converted constant expression of type bool (until
> C++23)an expression contextually converted to bool, where the
> conversion is a constant expression (since C++23). If the value is
> true, then statement-false is discarded (if present), otherwise,
> statement-true is discarded.

2. What 'instantiaded' mean ?

> If a constexpr if statement appears inside a templated entity, and if
> condition is not value-dependent after instantiation, the discarded
> statement is not instantiated when the enclosing template is
> instantiated .

3. What 'checked' mean? I understand that 'checked' means the code was totally compiled and verified for any possible error at that time.

> Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. if
> constexpr is not a substitute for the #if preprocessing directive:

Comment: Discarded: skipped, ignored, as if it wasn't there.

Comment: Instantiated: used in the context of templates. Means that the template is "embodied" (in fact *defined*) using the given concrete template arguments.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: More complicated than that, as explained in point2 and 3. *"discarded"* is really misleading IMO.

Comment: @jarod42, i am used to basic/ classic usage. I didn't read the ISO about templates although

Comment: Checked: it needs to be a valid statement anyway. (Even though it can be discarded.)

Comment: @jarod42. I created some code with templates and functions to understand the behavior, such "return different types, in a `if-substatement` and another in `else-substatement`". I also tried writing wrong syntax expressions for discarded statements.

Comment: In fact, point 1 differentiates the two blocks and **name** the statement/branch which doesn't satisfy the condition, to give it some "properties" afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void foo() {
    T t;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,std::string>){
        std::cout << t.find("asd");
    } else {
        t = 0;
        std::cout << t;
    }
}

int main () {
    foo<int>();                     // (2)
}
```

When `T` is a type that does not have a `find` method, then `std::cout << t.find("asd")` is an error. Nevertheless, the template is ok.

> 2. What 'instantiaded' mean ?

The template is instantiated in `(2)`. `foo` is just a template, instantiating it results in a function `foo<int>` that you can call.

> 1. What does 'discarded' mean in the text below?

The true-branch is discarded when `foo<int>` is instantiated (because the condition is `false`). Hence, even though `int` has no `find` method, the code compiles without error.

Now consider this similar, but very different example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    int x = 0;
    if constexpr (true) {
        std::cout << x;
    } else {
        x.find("asd");
    }
}
```

> 3. What 'checked' mean?

The text is a little contrived, it says that in the above example the `false` branch is discarded, but nevertheless it is checked, because it is outside of a template. It is just the english term: "checked" means the compiler checks if the code is correct. `int` has no method `find`, hence the above results in an error:

```
<source>:8:15: error: request for member 'find' in 'x', which is of non-class type 'int'
    8 |             x.find("asd");
      |               ^~~~
```

Even though this statement is never executed, it must be valid code.

Comment: what if a change `std::cout << t.find("asd");` in your first code, to `whatever contains errors`?.

Comment: @Roman then its the same. std::cout << t.find("asd"); is an error when t is an int. You can replace it with a different error and still `foo<int>()` compiles. Only when T == std::string the code in the true-branch is not discarded and checked